# Increasing pagesize on expanding the kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a KendoGrid with thousands of records. Initially I want to show the grid in shrinked view with 5 items in grid over my dashboard with expand button on the grid. When user click on the expand button then the items in grid should increased to 20.

For expanding my grid over dashboard i using the below code:

```
function Expand(widgetName, speed) {
        var widget = $("#" + widgetName + "Widget");
        debugger;
        var gridName = widgetName + "Grid";
        gridName.data().kendoGrid.dataSource.page(20);
        widget.css({ "z-index": 100 });
        GetWidget(widgetName).expanded = true;
        var expandedHeight = GetExpandedHeight(widgetName);
        widget.animate(
            {
                top: '5',
                height: expandedHeight
            },
            speed,
            function () {
                // Animation complete.
                var grid = $("#" + widgetName + "Grid");
                if (grid.length > 0) {
                    grid.animate(
                        { height: expandedHeight - 70 },
                        speed / 3,
                        function () {
                            resizeGrid(grid);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pageSize method and then call .read() again, such as:

```
gridName.data().kendoGrid.dataSource.pageSize(20);
gridName.data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read();
```